# how to customize json feed C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

i tried to develope json feed in C# . but unable get it my requirement

below i have added my code

```
public string ConvertDataTabletoString()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from table4", connection);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        da.Fill(dt);
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new  JavaScriptSerializer();

        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        return serializer.Serialize(rows);
    }
```

i got a below output .
all values comming from database.

```
[

    {
        "username":"raja",
        "empid":"45"
    },
    {
        "username":"z",
        "empid":"z"
    },
    {
        "username":"sdfs",
        "empid":"dfsdfsd"
    },
    {
        "username":"df",
        "empid":"d"
    }

]
```

but my requirement below format.how to change my output below format

```
 {
            "contacts":[
            {
            "username":"raja",
            "employee":{
            "empid":"45"
            }
            }
            ]
            }
```

Comment: How do you expect email,address etc. to be included in your final json without getting them from somewhere?

Comment: i want to know how to add "contacts" in json feed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to know how to add "contacts" in json feed

Just use an anonymous object to serialize

```
return serializer.Serialize(new { contacts = rows } );
```

Comment: thanks its working fine.how to add "phone" in json feed

Comment: `row.Add("phone",new{mobile="xxxx",home="yyyy"});`

Comment: please give me useful links for my question

Comment: row.Add("phone",new{mobile="xxxx",home="yyyy"}) its working fine.but how to add "phone" my code